# Are there any recommended resources for exploring the dynamics of power relationships within the context of teacher-student interactions?

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy, education, philosophy-of-social-sciences, authority

I am interested in the interplay of power within the educational setting, specifically focusing on the role of the teacher as a potential authoritarian figure akin. It seems that the traditional hierarchy of knowledge dissemination might contain inherent power structures that influence the dynamics of learning. thank you in advance!